# InstallCert.java crashes server before certificates are retrieved

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, dropwizard

I have a server running on Dropwizard (i.e. running Jetty for its web server). I'm trying to set up SSL for it.

I have a certificate signed by a CA (specifically Comodo, through Namecheap). I installed the root and intermediate certificates, then installed my own certificate (using the instructions on [Comodo's support](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/638/0/certificate-installation-java-based-web-servers-tomcat-using-keytool). Nonetheless, when I attempt to connect to my server for the first time (it boots fine), I get an error: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` (Of course the stack trace is much longer, but that's the root cause.)

I've tried searching this error, and consistently people say it should only happen for self-signed certificates, which mine is not. Nonetheless, I tried downloading the InstallCert.java program that seems to have originated from a (now removed) article on the Sun blog. Specifically I got the degree from [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/).

After several (failed) attempts to get it to work by command line (that's a discussion for another time), I eventually got it to run properly. Now the output I get from the program is:

```
Loading KeyStore C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\security\cacerts...
Opening connection to localhost:8443...
Starting SSL handshake...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.aw.ad.util.InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Meanwhile, if I open the window with my website, it once more delivers the `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` error and crashed (hence leading to the timeout). In essence, what it seems to me is that InstallCerts (which should fix my SSL problems) is crashing my server due to the SSL issues.

If I try using something like `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -showcerts` (which was a recommendation I saw somewhere, save the results of that to a .pem file and install that), the same thing happens.

Is there a solution this problem? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Note that my root/intermediate certificates were installed to the same keystore as my CSR and certificate. In the Dropwizard config file, I have trustStorePath and trustStorePassword set (to that keystore file). It's possible this might be related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be missing the whole chain of certificates from Comodo root CA to your site's certificate. Examine the keystore that you configured in Dropwizard and see if you have them all. The simplest way is to look for the issuer of your certificate, you need to have the certificate with the same subject, next look for the issuer of that certificate and so forth. To be sure try to chain authority key identifier certificate extension of your certificate with the key fingerprint (key identifier) of the issuer, and the issuer's issuer. If you provide

```
keytool -list -keystore <your keystore> -rfc
```

I might be able to help you more...

*Added later:*

I've managed to reproduce your problem exactly. TL;DR; add:

```
validateCerts: true
trustStorePath: lyonesgamer.com.keystore
enableCRLDP: true
```

I created a keystore containing the chain (single entry, 3 certificates, ca, subordinate ca and end entity certificate) and another keystore containing only the two ca certificates as trusted entries. Then I configured `keyStorePath`, `keyStorePassword`, `trustStorePath` and `validateCerts: true`.

This resulted in:
    `java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to validate certificate: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

After adding `-Djava.security.debug=certpath` I noticed that revocation checking was failing, and that this in fact was the root cause of certificate chain failure:

```
certpath: SunCertPathBuilder.depthFirstSearchForward(): validation failed:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status
```

Then I remembered that if you do not enable CRL Distribution Point extension usage for the CertPath API you need to specify the CRL yourself. Fortunately Dropwizard has an option to enable the CRLDP: `enableCRLDP: true`. With it enabled application successfully starts.

Alternatively you could keep the CRL in a file and point `crlPath` to it.

Comment: The full result of that command is here: http://pastebin.com/z7q85zc5 That's all 4 certificates Comodo sent me: the root (called AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt), two intermediates (COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt and COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt), and my certificate + private key.

Comment: Yup, your keystore looks fine, the whole chain is present.Number of certificates use 2048bit keys, is your Java instalation export restricted? Try installing Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) for your version.

Comment: I installed the unlimited strength files, but it had no effect. Same error.

Comment: Could you run the client and server with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl and put outputs to pastebin?

Comment: Server output: http://pastebin.com/FVVKDGJL

Client output is pretty similar, but: http://pastebin.com/gw9YTDjp

Comment: I'm looking at io.dropwizard.jetty.HttpsConnectorFactory and I would expect if trustStore parameter is not set that keyStorePath would be used for setting trust store. Try setting the trustStore parameter to the same as keyStorePath. From the jetty source code (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/9.2.2.v20140723/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#290) I would argue that its required.

Comment: And the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl didn't help much in this case ;(

Comment: Yeah, I have both keyStorePath and trustStorePath set to the keystore I used both to generate my CSR and to import all the certificates (both mine and the root/intermediate). I'm not sure why the output with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl gave me a blank keystore and the default trust store. Possibly the difference between Dropwizard's and Java's key/trust store? Or maybe just printed before the config was loaded (which isn't the first thing Dropwizard does on load).

Comment: I suggest then that you debugg by setting the breakpoint in doStart() of org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory (or in the constructor of org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateValidator) and see what is passed as trustStore. Do you use SSL in the initialization of your application, like try to connect to another service via https? If that's the case then the first lines of ssl debug output are caused by that (which is using the defaults).

Comment: I set a breakpoint in doStart(), and I'm seeing the variables _keyStore, _keyStoreInputStream, _trustStore, and _trustStoreInputStream are all null, but the variables _keyStorePath and _trustStorePath are set to the proper path to my keystore.

Comment: And no, I don't have any SSL calls in my application. My application doesn't call any other services.

Comment: Although I have found something I had apparently missed. The application does _not_ crash when I try to connect to it. It simply crashes after a given amount of time. If I simply let it run, it still crashes with the same error. Which is weird, because (for testing this error), I turned off validateCerts in the config file...

Answer (score 0):

After all this time, I'd been chasing a rabbit hole. It turned out the problem was that I (rather naively) was testing this on my own computer. Dropwizard's validation saw an error, because the certificate was only valid for my domain, which my personal computer is not a member of. Hence it crashed because it couldn't validate.

I discovered this by turning validateCerts off in my Dropwizard config file (I had thought I'd turned it off already, but apparently not). Dropwizard booted fine and allowed me to connect. When I did, then Firefox gave me an Untrusted Connection error, and clicking on Details gave me the much more useful information:

```
localhost:8443 uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is only valid for the following names: lyonesgamer.com, www.lyonesgamer.com
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

Thank you, Zoran, very much for trying to help. I'm afraid much of it was in vain.

Comment: Glad you got it working at last. Not sure that this is the root of your problem, see my edited answer.

Comment: The way it was described in the Dropwizard docs makes it sound like OCSP is an alternative to CRL. I have OCSP turned on and pointed to the referrer URL Comodo gave me. Do I still need to also have CRLDP turned on too?

Comment: The CRLDP is an attribute (called extension) of the certificate that points to revocation information be it CRL or OCSP, if you do not have it enabled then revocation checker cannot locate the said CRL or OCSP location. So you need to enable it...

Comment: Well, that seemed to do it. I added that and set validateCerts back to true, and it doesn't crash on startup. Firefox still gives me the same error, of course, but that's to be expected. Thank you so much for your help.